# why useState return empty array in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to receive an array from useState when I click the first time on submit ,the usestate return an empty array and  this make a probleme ?

```
const [order,setOrder] = useState([]);

const submit = (e) => {

 var NU =document.querySelector('#orderDesignation').value;
  var d =document.querySelector('#orderPrix').value;
   var p = document.querySelector('#origin').value;

     var q =document.querySelector('#orderQuntite').value;
    var t =document.querySelector('#orderPrixHT').value;


const  s = { orderDesignation: "d" ,orderPrix: "p" ,orderQuntite: "q" ,orderPrixHT:"t" }

console.log("s -->",s);

//s --> Object { orderDesignation: "dss", orderPrix: "1", orderQuntite: "3", orderPrixHT: 2 }

setOrder(order => [...order,s] );
 
console.log("order =",order);   //    order = Array[]   empty !!!! ?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because setOrder command is not a immediate command ,React may delay it and because your console.log is in next line in same function, it will returns the default value of order that is empty array.

Comment: you can try to change your default order state and check your console.log to be sure.

Comment: how can I wait  all  data for save  in Usestate  before console.log() ?